# Importing Multiple text File to Matlab

Tags: matlab, import

I need to import some text files as matrix In Matlab. Can anyone help me for code please? Here is the my text file names.

```
elist_S06n1.txt
elist_S06n2.txt
elist_S06n3.txt
elist_S06n4.txt
elist_S07n1.txt
elist_S07n2.txt
elist_S07n3.txt
elist_S07n4.txt
.
.
.
elist_S27n5.txt
```

So, till `elist_S09n1.tx` `n`  is going 1 through 4, then it is going 1 through 5.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far. Do you have problems with constructing proper [loops](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/for.html), [turning numeric values into strings](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) for your filename, or [importing data](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/data-import-and-export.html)?

Comment: I just tried to revise following code, but because file names, I did not manage. 
numfiles = 95;
mydata = cell(1, numfiles);

for k = 1:numfiles
  myfilename = sprintf('file%d.txt', k);
  mydata{k} = importdata(myfilename);
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your update so we can see what you have tried so far.

It seems to me that you have difficulties generating the proper filename. Instead of looping over your cell array index, you could use two loops, one from 6 to 27 and the other from 1 to 4 or 5. Based on these values, you can easily generate the desired filename (mind the leading zero!). Within the loop, you keep track of an index for the resulting cell array.

By the way, if I count the number of files, I arrive at a total of 18*5 + 4*4 = 106 and not 95.

The code:

```
numfiles = (27-9)*5 + (9-5)*4;
mydata = cell(1, numfiles);

idx = 0; % index for mydata
n = 4;
for k1 = 6:27
    if k1 == 10
        n = 5; % switch to 5 files if k1 reaches 10
    end
    for k2 = 1:n
        idx = idx+1;
        myfilename = sprintf('elist_S%02dn%d.txt', k1, k2);
        mydata{idx} = importdata(myfilename);
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Jan. Appreciated.